# How to check if server is open or not and display a messsagebox

Tags: mysql, vb6

hhi!! i want to display a messagebox if the server is nnot started this is the code for the class1, in this code when the xampp and mysql server is not open they shows the error so me i want that they show the messagebox 'not connected tyr again'!!.

this is the code for the class1

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
DoEvents
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
With con

.ConnectionString = "Driver={MYSQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver} ;server=localhost;pwd=;uid=root;port=3306;database=kibaza;"
.CursorLocation = adUseClient
.Open
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Use an error handler, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266173(v=vs.60).aspx.

Comment: As a general rule, any code with "DoEvents" in it should be viewed with suspicion (you got this code from somewhere, I presume).  While there is a place for it, 95% of the times that you see it it isn't necessary, and is put in by coders who heard it was a good idea for some vague reason.  As a general rule, don't use DoEvents unless you know exactly which event handlers are in the queue, and that you want to stop what you are doing, run them, and go back to executing your program.  An example might be interrupting a loop to update a ProgressBar control.

Answer (score 3):

Add an error handler to you code.

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    DoEvents

    On Error GoTo err_Class_Initialize

    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    With con
        .ConnectionString = "Driver={MYSQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver} ;server=localhost;pwd=;uid=root;port=3306;database=kibaza;"
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open
    End With

    Exit Sub

err_Class_Initialize:
    'You can just display the error to the user, or you can examine the err number and make decisions
    MsgBox "There was an error opening the connection." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Error: " & CStr(Err.Number) & ", " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Initialization Error"

End Sub
```

Comment: better exit sub before that handler else it will always run

Comment: @AlexK.Thanks, I did miss that.

Answer (score 0):

Using the idea of "jac", put a "err.number <> 0" in this way the "GoTo" is activated only when there is an error:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
DoEvents

On Error GoTo err_Class_Initialize

Set con = New ADODB.Connection
With con
    .ConnectionString = "Driver={MYSQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver} ;server=localhost;pwd=;uid=root;port=3306;database=kibaza;"
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open
End With

err_Class_Initialize:
if err.number <> 0 then
    'You can just display the error to the user, or you can examine the err number and make decisions
    MsgBox "There was an error opening the connection." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Error: " & CStr(Err.Number) & ", " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Initialization Error"
end if
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a complete rewrite.

Don't try to establish the connection during the Class_Initialize event.  Instead add some sort of Connect method.

Declare the Connection `WithEvents` and open asynchronously.  Implement a handler for the Connection object's `ConnectComplete` event.  There you can process the `adStatus` and `Error` object to determine success or failure and raise an event back to your class's client indicating the status.

You seem to be trying to use ADO in the most primitive way imaginable.  Be careful with code snippets you find on the web, much of it stems from creaky 1990s ASP VBScript samples.